# how does grep only today's files in current directory?

Tags: shell

I want to grep files which created today in the current directory. So how many ways to do that? What's the best way to do that?

```
grep --color 'content' ./directory
```

Comment: `find ./directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime 0 | xargs grep --color 'content'`?

Comment: @YangXu: What do you mean by **created**? Are you refering to the inode-change time of the file, or the time of last modification? What OS are you using?

Comment: @user1934428 last modify time.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Yeah, it worked， but if I want to specify a particular time with find, which option should I use？

Comment: There is a `-newermt` option that allows you to specify a time in the format `"2021-07-02 12:31:29"` if you want exact control. That will given you files with modification time  newer than the time specified. E.g. `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "2021-07-02 02:10:00"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```sh
find ./directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -daystart -ctime 0 -print | xargs grep --color 'content'
```

In the above command, we are using `find` to find all the files (`-type f`) in `directory`, that were made today (`-daystart -ctime 0`) and then `-print` the full files paths to standard output. We then send the output to `xargs`. Using `xargs` we are able to execute each line of the output through the `grep` command. This is much simpler than having to create a `for` loop and iterate over each line of the output.

Comment: Great minds think alike `:)` I do like your use of `-daystart` rather than a simple 24-hour block.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you want to grep `"content"` within all file in `./directory` modified today, then you can use a combination of `find` and `xargs`. For example to find the files in `./directory` modified today, you can give the `-mtime 0` option which find files modified `0` 24 hour periods ago (e.g. today). To handle strange filenames, use the `-print0` option to have `find` output nul-terminated filenames. Your find command could be:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime 0 -print0
```

One the list of files is generated, you can pass the result to `xargs -0` which will process the list of filenames as being nul-terminated and using your `grep` command, you would have:

```
xargs -0 grep --color 'content'
```

To put it altogether, simply pipe the result of `find` to `xargs`, e.g.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime 0 -print0 | 
xargs -0 grep --color 'content'
```

Give that a go and let me know if it does what you need or if you have further questions.

**Edit Per Comment**

If you want more exact control of the hour, or minute or second from which you want to select your files, you can use the `-newermt` option for `find` to file all files newer than the date you give as the option, e.g. `-newermt "2021-07-02 02:10:00"` would select today's file created after `2:10:00` (all files after 2:10:00 am this morning)

Modifying the test above and replacing `-mtime 0` with `-newermt "2021-07-02 02:10:00"` you would have:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "2021-07-02 02:10:00"` -print 0 |
xargs -0 grep --color 'content'
```

(adjust the time to your exact starting time you want to begin selecting files from)

Give that a go also. It is quite a bit more flexible as you can specify any time within the day to begin selecting files from based on the files modification time.